# HTML encoding issue

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding

So I'm making a website in Spanish. The .html file is saved as utf-8, and even declared

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in the `<head>` of the page, but I'm still having trouble showing characters such as ñ or á.

What can I do?

Comment: Is this content coming from a database?

Comment: That should be all, unless you have it nested in a master page perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Its the index page! most of the js is in this same file inside de <script> tag. Theres some js in other files, should i verify encoding for those files?

Comment: Theres no database involved!

Comment: What is the actual Content-Type header sent by the server? If you save the page via your browser and open that copy, does it display the expected characters then?

Comment: Thanks Darsstar! Apparently its my browser, entered the page from another pc and i see the characters just fine!